# BlurView library has no effect on the screen

Tags: java, android, xml, blur

I tried to use Dimezis's BlurView [library](https://github.com/Dimezis/BlurView) to create a blur effect on android, but it hasn't worked at all.

I followed all the directions, but still it hasn't had any effect.

Here is the main activity layout that I inserted the BlurView layout xml into:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.mistplay.mistplay.MainActivity">

    <eightbitlab.com.blurview.BlurView
        android:id="@+id/blurView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:blurOverlayColor="#78ffffff">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabGravity="fill"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    </eightbitlab.com.blurview.BlurView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here is the code where I attempted to blur the screen in MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    updateBalanceandCheckTutorial();

    if (UserManager.getInstance().getShouldShowTutorial()) {

        BlurView blurView = (BlurView) findViewById(R.id.blurView);

        final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        final ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.mainRoot);
        final Drawable windowBackground = decorView.getBackground();

        blurView.setupWith(rootView)
                    .windowBackground(windowBackground)
                    .blurAlgorithm(new SupportRenderScriptBlur(this))
                    .blurRadius(10);
    }
}
```

If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong that would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the window background? Also `BlurView can be used only in a hardware-accelerated window. Otherwise, blur will not be drawn. It will fallback to a regular FrameLayout drawing process.` as said in https://github.com/Dimezis/BlurView#important